# Using Drush to upgrade Drupal

Tags: 7, drush

I'm trying to determine if I can migrate a site from 6 to 7 with Drush 7. I get this, "Error: Call to undefined function drush_sql_empty_db()", and I did some searching and this function does not seem to exist in Drush 7. On the drush_sup page it says to use Drush 6 or later, which would insinuate that Drush 7 is compatible. Any insight would be appreciated, I'm not in the mood to downgrade my Drush installation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The function `drush_sql_empty_db()` has been removed in Drush 7.  You have two choices:

1. Downgrade to Drush 6 (it is possible to install Drush 6 at a different location, and alias 'drush6' to point to the older version).
2. Fix the site upgrade command.

The equivalent function to `drush_sql_empty_db()` in Drush 7 is:

```
$sql = drush_sql_get_class();
$sql->drop_or_create();
```

There may be other issues with Drush site-upgrade and Drush 7; I have not tried it in a while.